# Android apps links For Creating Php

Tags: php, android

I am trying to create a php of android. I don't know how to the view source code of android apk. I have cracked an apk to find out links.

Here is code of that apk file in which I want to find out web links to create script.

```
package com.pokketdeal.corp.api;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.pokketdeal.corp.customclasses.Utils;
import com.pokketdeal.corp.models.BasicResponse;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;

public abstract class APICallback<T, E> implements Callback<T> {
    private static final int RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS = 101;
    Context _context;

    public abstract void onFailure(String str);

    public abstract void onSuccess(E e);

    public APICallback(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return this._context;
    }

    public void onNetworkFailure() {
    }

    public void retryRequest() {
    }

    public final void success(T serviceResponse, Response response) {
        BasicResponse basicResponse = (BasicResponse) serviceResponse;
        if (basicResponse.getResponseCode() != RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            String errorMessage = Utils.getStringResource(this._context, "response_code_" + basicResponse.getResponseCode());
            if (errorMessage == null) {
```

What are the web links for this apk?

Comment: It's not in that class. It can be anywhere. Could be in the class that makes the request, can be in the activity that call the class that makes the request, can be in one of the resource files (ie. strings.xml). It can be in many places.

Comment: pleasegive any example which type of link will be??

Comment: What do you mean by `type of link will be` ?

Comment: i mean how to find out web links to creat php and in which file i will get

Comment: You will need to look at the codes of the entire package. But you can try looking at apps like `OS Monitor`, it will show you where apps on your device are connecting to.

Comment: bro i have try out that one also in which shows the package name but where is web links

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, you have an android app that connects to a server and does some work and you want to know which URLs it uses?